# How to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline job with bitbucket repo webhook

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, jenkins-groovy

I am using jenkins pipeline job where all of my pipeline steps have been mentioned in bitbucket as am using shared library methodology. Here am passing branch name as a parameter. so every job will use same pipeline template but branch name will be different.

The only problem am facing currently is how do i trigger the jenkins pipeline build when any change is happening in branch at bitbucket level.

I have tried bitbucket webhook, but that doesn't seems to be helpin as i couldn't create it for every branch seperately.

Note: am not using scm checkout step in pipeline, am executing the shell step for cloning with "git clone  -b . Because if we use pipeline with scm then we need to keep all our pipeline steps into jenkinsfile at bitbucket level.

Can anyone please share how you guys are configuring the shared library pipeline script for poll scm?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Are you passing the branch name as a param and want that branch to be pulled? In that case, you can specify the branch name in the [GitSCM plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/).

On the other hand if you want to watch for changes in Bitbucket, you can use the [branch source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source/) plugin. You can refer to the docs [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.adoc). If you want the branches to be discovered and built automatically, refer to [this section](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.adoc#branches-and-pull-requests-auto-discovering).